# Scala string to array double quoted elements

Tags: string, scala, split, double-quotes

In Scala, how can I convert a comma separated string to an array with double quoted elements?

I have tried as below:

```
var string = "welcome,to,my,world"
var array = string.split(',').mkString("\"", "\",\"", "\"")
Output:
[ "\"welcome\",\"to\",\"my\",\"world\""]
```

My requirement is for the array to appear as:

```
["welcome","to","my","world"]
```

I also tried using the below method:

```
var array = string.split(",").mkString(""""""", """","""", """"""")
Output:["\"ENV1\",\"ENV2\",\"ENV3\",\"ENV5\",\"Prod\""]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mkString` makes string out of sequence. If you need an array as a result you just need to map the elements to add quotes.

```
val str = "welcome,to,my,world"

val arr = 
    str
    .split( ',' )
    .map( "\"" + _ + "\"" )

arr.foreach( println )
```

Output

```
"welcome"
"to"
"my"
"world"
```

Comment: With the solution you have suggested , what I get is `output is :[
                "\"welcome\"", "\"to\"", "\"my\"","\"world\""
            ]`

Comment: Array of strings is naturally represented as `[ "something", "something" ]`. You wanted additional double quotes to each element - here they are.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, as your example result does not contain double quotes. This would generate a string that looks like your requirement, but not sure if that's what you're looking for?

```
var string = "welcome,to,my,world"
string.split(',').mkString("[\"","\",\"","\"]")`

res9: String = ["welcome","to","my","world"]`
```